# AndroidStudio: Добавить слово в исключение в "Colors & Fonts"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Подсветка синтаксиса в AndroidStudio, при разработке на Kotlin, превращает текст программы в кашу, т.к. **val** **var** **fun** подсвечивается одинаково. Как добавить отдельную подсветку для отдельной фразы (хочу добавить в исключение ***fun***)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->Kotlin` - там много чего можно под себя настроить.

Но, насколько я понимаю, `var`, `val` и `fun` - это все `keywords` и задаются одним стилем. В качестве workaround можете задать вырвиглазный цвет для `Functions -> Function Declaration`

Comment: Спасибо, на безрыбье и рак рыба :)